# How null DATETIME column

Tags: mysql, sql

Have a table `users` and column 'users_update1' (DATETIME)
Need that column 'users_update1' was nulled after 10 minutes

That dont work. Need help

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET users_update1 = NULL, WHERE DATE_SUB(users_update1,INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)";
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE users_update1 < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600)";
$sql = "UPDATE users SET users_update1 = NULL, WHERE users_update1 = NOW() - 600";
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you don't want to be updating columns frequently, if you can avoid it.  Instead, use a view.

```
create view v_users as
    select u.col1, u.col2, . . .,  -- all columns other than `users_update1`
           (case when DATE_ADD(users_update1, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) > now()
                 then users_update1
            end) as users_update1
    from users u;
```

This uses logic to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: maybe I explained bad .. I just need to column 'users_update1' in the table 'users' was like 0000-00-00 00:00:00

script make in 'users_update1' day-time and I need that after 10 minut day-time was nulled

Comment: UPDATE users
SET users_update1 = NULL
WHERE DATE_ADD(users_update1, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) < NOW()

it work!! yeah!